# db.collection.find() taking too much to return complete data

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nosql

I am doing the following to pull complete data from MongoDB collection.

```
db_client = MongoClient(host='host')
db_database = db_client['db_name']
raw_data = db_database.collection_name.find()
result_data = [row for row in raw_data]
return result_data
```

It is taking too much time to return. What is the best way to fetch complete data from the collection?

Comment: Use cursor operation rather than array...

Comment: You mean cursor.toArray()? It is not working.

Comment: no, access the returned documents one by one by calling cursor.next() until the end of result.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of documents, this line:

```
result_data = [row for row in raw_data]
```

is where Python spends most of its time.

Depending on what you want to do with the documents, you may be able to do:

```
for row in raw_data:
    # process each row
    print row
```

However, if you intend to return the whole collection and not processing it, you are doing a collection scan (equivalent to a table scan in SQL) and creating a large Python data structure. By definition, either processes won't be fast. Combined, they're going to be very slow, and there's no workaround that I'm aware of.

If your intent is to dump the whole collection, you may want to look at [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) or [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) instead, which are designed to perform this task.

Comment: I am trying to move data from MongoDB to MySQL database. The problem is on an average every minute there is a new entry in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the list comprehension step completely (which is probably the reason for the lag) by converting the cursor to a list right off the bat:

```
raw_data = list(db_database.collection_name.find())
```

Comment: It returns [object].